# Unsupported driver [ecto] in Laravel 8 project. Where is this ecto coming from?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ecto

I'm trying to kick off my queuec consumer for a php app I inherited.  When I run:

```
php artisan queue:listen database --sleep=10 --timeout=0 --memory=3000 --queue="default"
```

I get an error for an unsupported driver [ecto].

```
#24 {main}
"} 

   InvalidArgumentException 

  Unsupported driver [ecto].

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php:287
    283▕             case 'sqlsrv':
    284▕                 return new SqlServerConnection($connection, $database, $prefix, $config);
    285▕         }
    286▕ 
  ➜ 287▕         throw new InvalidArgumentException("Unsupported driver [{$driver}].");
    288▕     }
    289▕ }
    290▕

      +23 vendor frames 
  24  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

It's very clear where and why this is happening from a look at the code.  "ecto" is not supported so we explicitly throw an exception in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php`:

```
258     /**
259      * Create a new connection instance.
260      *
261      * @param  string  $driver
262      * @param  \PDO|\Closure  $connection
263      * @param  string  $database
264      * @param  string  $prefix
265      * @param  array  $config
266      * @return \Illuminate\Database\Connection
267      *
268      * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
269      */
270     protected function createConnection($driver, $connection, $database, $prefix = '', array $config = [])
271     {
272         if ($resolver = Connection::getResolver($driver)) {
273             return $resolver($connection, $database, $prefix, $config);
274         }
275 
276         switch ($driver) {
277             case 'mysql':
278                 return new MySqlConnection($connection, $database, $prefix, $config);
279             case 'pgsql':
280                 return new PostgresConnection($connection, $database, $prefix, $config);
281             case 'sqlite':
282                 return new SQLiteConnection($connection, $database, $prefix, $config);
283             case 'sqlsrv':
284                 return new SqlServerConnection($connection, $database, $prefix, $config);
285         }
286 
287         throw new InvalidArgumentException("Unsupported driver [{$driver}].");
288     }
289 }
```

I can't find anything about a thing called `Ecto` in the context of PHP anywhere other than a person's github username that has published a php repo.

The weirdest thing is that I do a lot of Elixir/Phoenix development where Ecto is the "ORM."  I wondered if somehow that was contaminating things, but running the php app in a container without a trace of Elixir/Ecto gives me the same error.

I've seen advised in many places to clear the config:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

but that doesn't change anything for me.

I grepped through whole repo (including `vendor/` and `ecto` doesn't seem to appear anywhere.  Where could this driver be coming from?  How do I debug this?

Comment: Can you edit your question with the output of `dd(config('database'));` (be careful, remove any credentials)?

Comment: @AnthonyAslangul thanks for the hint!  Once I did that it didn't take long to figure out where it was coming from :-)   I wish up voting your comment would give you karma.  If you want to post an answer I'll accept it.  I posted one also to help others in the future but I'll accept yours if you post one.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the hint from [Anthony Aslangui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3330212/anthony-aslangul), I figured it out.  the `ecto` was coming from an env var that wasn't namespaced and clashed with the Elixir app.

`DATABASE_URL` was set to `ecto://...`  So it *was* related to Elixir's Ecto!  I namespaced the env vars and redeployed and the problem is gone.

The hint that really helped was running `dd(config('database'));`.  I used the [Laravel REPL](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#tinker) to do so:

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.10.8 (PHP 7.4.23 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> dd(config('database'));                                
array:4 [                     
  "default" => "mysql"
  "connections" => array:5 [
  ...
```